# How to check promise value and property updated in promise but not returned with chai-as-promised

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai-as-promised

I have a promise which checks if I'm authorized or not (returning true or false).
Within that promise, when authorization is false, I'm also adding the 403 statusCode to the response object that I pass as a parameter.
I'm testing the result of my promise with chai-as-promised but I didn't manage to find a way to also test the status code of the response after the promise is resolved.

```
var result = authorizePromise(request, response);
return expect(result).to.eventually.equal(false).and(response.statusCode.should.be(403));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the response should be used in parent scope.
and the assertion should be called after the promise is ready
so it should be a function that called *after*.
your code example `.and(response.statusCode.should.be(403));` runs the assertion instant, and passes it as parameter to `.and()` it does not wait for the promise.

*You can use `.and`instead of `.then` too.

```js
var response = {};
var resultPromise = authorizePromise(request, response);
return expect(resultPromise).to.eventually.equal(false)
    .then(function(){return response.statusCode.should.be(403)})
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about using .then to make sure that my promise is resolved when checking the result.